# How to do ascending of two data with null values in between

Tags: mysql

MySQL is having data like this.

```
ID----Name----InTime----OutTime 
1---Person1 ---10:30---  NULL
2--- Person2--- NULL---10:34 
3--- Person3---10:35---10:40 
4---Person4---10:33--10:45
5---Person5---NULL--10:50
6---Person6---10:40---NULL
```

I am trying to fetch data and get output like this.

```
ID----Name----InTime----OutTime 
 1---Person1 ---10:30---  NULL
3--- Person4---10:33--10:45
 2--- Person2--- NULL---10:34 
 4---Person3---10:35---10:40
5---Person6---10:40---NULL
6---Person5---NULL--10:50
```

To get this I am using following query,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY INTime ASC, OutTime ASC
```

I want to first ASC the InTime then put OutTime in between matching InTime ASC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below query**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN INTime IS NULL THEN OutTime ELSE INTime END) ASC
```

Comment: See COALESCE().

Answer (score 0):

```
select MyDate
from MyTable
order by case when MyDate is null then 1 else 0 end, MyDate
```